# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 no server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-config-manager

I am unable to connect to a server in Microsoft SQL Server 2014. As you can see in the image below there doesn't seem to be any Server services. Any idea what I could be missing to make this work?  Also in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I tried different types of Server names, like  COMPUTER_NAME\SQLEXPRESS and still does not work.

[image: No Servers :(]

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed SQL Server.

Comment: I am rather confused. I have a folder called Microsoft SQL Server. It has folders like 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, Client SDK.

Comment: What **did** you install? Obviously not a database engine ..... just install it and then go about your tasks!

Comment: I installed SQL Server 2014 Management Studio 32/64-bit (English). But I think you are correct, seems like the installiation did not contain the actual server. Thanks for the help I wilkl go and download the Server.

Comment: Yeah,. the Management Studio download is just that - **only** the Management Studio (the GUI tool). You need to either get the SQL Server Express **with tools** (which includes the Mgmt Studio), or you need to separately download the actual database engine, too, to install both

Comment: Yea indeed, I figured it might have contained the server too but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not completed the installation of sqlserver , if full installation is complete you can find sql server in (win+R)and search ssms after that you can open through it.

Comment: Hey. The issue has been resolved. The issue was that I didn't install the actual server but only the SQL Server 2014 Management Studio 32/64-bit (English).